# Pycharm Remote Dev using SFTP with Yubi Key authentication

Tags: ssh, pycharm, yubikey

I have PyCharm Pro.  I am trying to do remote development on a server.  I have read the following Jetbrains tutorials:

[Deploying Applications](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/deploying-applications.html)

[Remote Development on Raspberry Pi](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-development-on-raspberry-pi.html#graph)

as well as the very helpful tutorial:

[Remote debugging with pycharm the missing tutorial](https://medium.com/@petrovy1/remote-debugging-with-pycharm-the-missing-tutorial-a3a42884bfed)

While I seem to be able to set everything up, authentication fails when I try to connect to the remote server using the 'SFTP' protocol.  I can make an SSH and SFTP connection from the CLI in a terminal so I know the ssh configuration settings are correct.  However, in my case authentication requires ssh and having a Yubi key connected to my laptop.  Does that make a difference?

Has anyone had a similar issue?  If so, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MacOS the challenge is where the IDE is getting it's ssh socket agent.  To make this work in my case I have to launch the PyCharm Pro IDE from a terminal.

Go to '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/MacOS' directory and launch with './pycharm'